# What's the difference between a named constant and a static (SAVE) variable, apart from being guaranteed immutable?

Tags: fortran, constants, static-variables

Comparing

```
INTEGER, SAVE :: foo = 3
```

to

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: foo = 3
```

in what ways do they behave different? Obviously the latter will trigger a compiler error when somebody attempts to mutate `foo`, but is this just like the `const` keyword in C / C++ or does it also imply something about storage location etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The `parameter` attribute is used to denote a named constant that is set at compile-time and cannot be changed at run-time. As such, it is similar to the `const` keyword. To cite the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 5.3.13 "PARAMETER attribute":

> 1 The PARAMETER attribute specifies that an entity is a named constant. The entity has the value specified by its constant-expr , converted, if necessary, to the type, type parameters and shape of the entity.
>
> [...]
>
> 2 A named constant shall not be referenced unless it has been defined previously in the same statement, defined in
>   a prior statement, or made accessible by use or host association.

The `save` attribute causes a variable to keep state after it gets out of scope, e.g. between consecutive calls to a subroutine or inside a module. Other than that, it behaves like a normal variable and can be changed at run-time. The Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 5.3.16 "SAVE attribute" states that

> 1 The SAVE attribute specifies that a local variable of a program unit or subprogram retains its association status, allocation status, definition status, and value after execution of a RETURN or END statement unless it is a
>   pointer and its target becomes undefined (16.5.2.5(5)). If it is a local variable of a subprogram it is shared by all instances (12.6.2.4) of the subprogram.

Comment: Yes, but what _is_ a named constant? What sets it apart from a named variable?

Comment: @leftaroundabout A named constant is a constant that cannot be changed at run-time.

Comment: Perhaps this crucial thing to say is that a named constant (or component of) may be referenced in a constant expression.  No variable may (except when inquired of).

Comment: @francescalus: could you elaborate / give an example (make it an answer)?

Comment: @francescalus To me the main difference is that a constant can only be used in an expression. And yes, the values of varables cannot occur in constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A constant is not a variable in the first place. It does not have any storage (conceptually). You cannot ask for its address. You cannot put it in context where a variable is required. You cannot point pointers at it. You can only use it in expressions.

For example consider

```
  INTEGER, SAVE :: foo = 3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: bar = 3
```

then

```
  call sub(foo)
```

passes the variable `foo` to the subroutine, while

```
  call sub(bar)
```

computes an expression (rather simple one), stores its value somewhere, and passes it to the subroutine.

You can also do

```
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: bar = 3
  INTEGER, SAVE :: foo = bar
```

while

```
  INTEGER, SAVE :: foo = 3
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: bar = foo
```

won't work. A constant value requires a constant expression.